# Monotonic watchdog timer in python

Tags: python, time, timer, pthreads, watchdog

I have a python code, which spawns another process. The child is given 20 seconds for execution. If not finished by that time, it needs to be killed.

Main:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Timer

proc = Popen(['./plugin.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
killer = Timer(20, proc.kill)
killer.start()

for line in proc.stdout:
    print('stdout: ' + line)

stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

Sample infinite child used for testing:

```
# cat plugin.sh
#!/bin/sh
count=1
while true; do
    echo "$(date) hello [$((count++))]"
    sleep 1
done
```

Normal execution is fine, child gets killed after 20 seconds.

```
stdout: Wed 01 Jun 2022 04:07:52 PM IST hello [1]
stdout: Wed 01 Jun 2022 04:07:53 PM IST hello [2]
...
stdout: Wed 01 Jun 2022 04:08:10 PM IST hello [19]
stdout: Wed 01 Jun 2022 04:08:11 PM IST hello [20]
#
```

Now, I want the main program to kill child after 20 seconds, irrespective of system time change.
With current code, if I manually change system time, child gets lesser or more time than 20 seconds allowance.

Example, when I change time backwards:

```
stdout: Wed 01 Jun 2022 04:14:44 PM IST hello [4]
stdout: Wed 01 Jun 2022 02:59:25 PM IST hello [5]
...
stdout: Wed 01 Jun 2022 02:59:41 PM IST hello [21]
stdout: Wed 01 Jun 2022 02:59:42 PM IST hello [22]
...
```

Found a related discussion here: https://bugs.python.org/issue31267

```
# python
Python 3.7.13 (default, May 27 2022, 08:39:11)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.thread_info
sys.thread_info(name='pthread', lock='semaphore', version='NPTL 2.30')
>>>
```

I am on Linux, and lock used is semaphore, not mutex+cond.

What is the alternate mechanism that I can use to make my timer independent of system time change?

Comment: just launching a `thread.Thread` and have it `time.sleep()` before calling `proc.kill()` should be monotonic, and i think `asyncio.wait()` is also monotonic, but you need to make an asyncio event loop.

Comment: also note that functions that wait/sleep are only guaranteed to wait at least the time they should wait, it may take a few seconds more depending on the availability of the gil at that time , (like if a long function is keeping the gil as hostage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API supports timeout, and it seems to work without being affected by system time change. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

```
import subprocess

try:
    proc = subprocess.run(['./plugin.sh'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            universal_newlines=True,
            timeout=10)
    for line in proc.stdout.splitlines():
        print('Plugin stdout: ' + line)

except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as t:
    for line in t.stdout.decode().splitlines():
        print('Plugin stdout: ' + line)
    print('Timed out')
```